# Python build GUI with a function

Tags: python

I want build a script that i give one input like a list (eg:`[["Name1",point,size],["Name2",point,size],etc]` and it create x labels with different names like label1,label2, etc

My problem is how Can i make the script build different labels?

Eg:

```
label1 = Text(center, "name1")
label2 = Text(center, "name2")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What library are you using? in python there are many libraries to make a GUI

Comment: You seem to know  how to make two. Why is that any different than creating 10?

Comment: @BryanOakley I think they want it in a loop

Comment: Have you ever used `tkinter` for building GUIs?

Comment: What are point, size, and center? Does center contain point and size?

Comment: At moment Im just wondering how I will do it, dont matter what library I will use ( I think).
I picked the example from module graphics but Im thinking use wxpython,
Yes, I want how create 2 or 10 or 1000. It will be dependent of a input.
Yes, I want some like a loop that create different variables/labels.
Point and size are just examples of what I should use to config that label. I have center just because I copied from another example.

Comment: What's stopping you from using a loop? Why haven't you tried using a loop to see what would happen?

Comment: the problem is not the loop, I just dont know I can create the names of variables label1, label2 without write it by myself. I can convert a string into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a list:

```
label_data = [["Name1",point,size],["Name2",point,size]]
```

What you need to do is just loop over it like:

```
label_vars = {}
for i in label_data:
    label_vars[i[0]] = Text(center,i[whatever],further_arguments) #Arguments can be given by i[1] or *i[1:n]
```

Comment: what is "i" there?

Comment: For every loop, `i` is a variable which will be assigned the value of current element. It changes to the next element in `label_data`, every time a loop completes a cycle

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer guys: `locals()`

I just need write some like:

```
data= [["Name1",point],["Name2",point]]
n=0
while n<len(data):
    new_name="label"+str(n)  
    locals()[new_name]= Text(data[n][1], data[n][0])
    n+=1
```

Comment: That is a horrible solution (the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) even explicitly states that you shouldn't modify the contents of `locals`) and most likely not what you should be doing. Why do you want to create new variables instead of using a list or dictionary?

Comment: I agree with @UnholySheep, It's the most horrible solution i've seen, this as worse as it can get.

Comment: I already told you: Create your own dictionary (something like `gui_elements = {}`) and put your elements in there - same as you are doing here, except you don't mess with the `locals` (e.g.: `gui_elements[new_name]= Text(data[n][1], data[n][0])`)

Comment: `from graphics import *


#win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
data = [["Name1", (30,30)], ["Name2", (70,70)]]
n=0
gui_elements={}
while n<len(data):
    new_name="label"+str(n)
    print new_name
    gui_elements[new_name]= Text(data[n][1], data[n][0])
    n+=1
print gui_elements`

I got    `self.anchor = p.clone()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'clone' `